# Reset the WebView state and release page resources without touching history stack

Tags: android, webview, browser-history

On android WebView documentation it was written that:
"public void clearView ()

Added in API level 1
This method was deprecated in API level 18.
Use WebView.loadUrl("about:blank") to reliably reset the view state and release page resources (including any running JavaScript)."
But I couldn't found any solution to remove the "about:blank" url from the history stack. Then when you pressing back button you have to stop on the "about:blank" url.

For my case I need to reset the WebView state and release page resources but should keep the history without "about:blank" url(s).

PS: clearHistory() clear all history, so it is not my solution.